# Prevent multiple selections of list items in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BexUR.png)

Hello everyone,

I have an unordered list and a textarea. what I wanted to do is when I click a list item it updates the textarea to show li value. the following code is working fine but the problem is when dragging and dropping inside the list the textarea will show the html code of the selected items as shown in the attached snapshot. How can I prevent multiple selections in this case?

```js
function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

var ul = document.getElementById('messages-list');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = getEventTarget(event);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <ul class="list-group" id="messages-list">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fifth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Sixth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Seventh item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Eighth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Nineth item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thnaks! it worked this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.innerHTML` when you are not interested in HTML results. You (as you have seen) will get markup that is parsed, which is more work that will be done for no reason. Use `.textContent` instead. And don't listen for click on the `ul`, listen for it on each `li`. By doing this, you don't have to worry about `target` vs. `srcElement` and you can completely get rid of the `getEventTarget()` function.

```js
// Don't scan the DOM for the same element over and over, cache the reference
var message = document.getElementById("message");

var ul = document.getElementById('messages-list');

// Get all the list items in the unordered list as a proper array:
var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(ul.querySelectorAll("li"));

// Loop through each list item
listItems.forEach(function(item){
  // Assign a click event handler to the list item
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    message.textContent = this.textContent;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <ul class="list-group" id="messages-list">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fifth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Sixth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Seventh item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Eighth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Nineth item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I really like this solution. I think it is more efficient... Appreciate your help...

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and mark the best one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your event listener to capture the click event on the `li`, not the `ul`

```js
function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onclick = function(event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <ul class="list-group" id="messages-list">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fifth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Sixth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Seventh item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Eighth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Nineth item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works this way. but check @Scott Marcus answer.

Comment: @Ray you're welcome. What do you want me to check about it? It's good advice, but I was just solving the question in your post and left the rest of your code alone.

Comment: @Ray no problem. Part of why I wouldn't suggest `textContent` over `innerHTML` is because I don't know your use case. I'm assuming your real code doesn't have "First item," "Second item," etc in the elements you want to copy. In this specific demo, `textContent` would be better. But if you put an html tag in there and you want to copy the tags (which I assumed you were doing, since you're using `innerHTML`) then the tags won't copy with `textContent`. So that's why I didn't modify it, I just solved the problem you posed in the question itself.

Comment: good point, I will keep that in mind if I needed to implement that (copying the tags) in the future. @michael .

Answer (score 0):

You can update your script as follows. Instead, you will loop through li elements instead and add your event listeners.

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

var area= document.getElementById("message");
var collection = document.getElementById('messages-list').getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var index=0, li; li= collection[index]; index++){
    li.onclick = function(event) {
      var target = getEventTarget(event);
      area.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
    };
}
```